# iTunes permissions on second drive

Tags: itunes, permission

I upgraded my mac to use an SSD for System and Applications and moved Users to a second HDD. iTunes will not allow me to authorize.

Here are my paths:

```
/Mac/... (System, etc)

/Volumes/Pig/Users/
  /Volumes/Pig/Users/arrow
  /Volumes/Pig/Users/Shared
  /Volumes/Pig/Users/wildcat
```

Currently permissions on Pig are 755 system:wheel on /Pig, /Pig/Users, and /Pig/Users/Shared.

Error on starting iTunes:

```
You do not have enough access privileges for this operation
```

Error on authorization attempt:

```
There was an error storing your authorization information on this computer.

The required directory was not found or has a permissions error. Correct this permissions problem and try again, or deauthorize this computer if the permissions cannot be changed.
```

This computer was previously authorized. I've deauthorized everything in my account so now we're starting zero. I've also followed the Apple Support Article regarding this issue. http://support.apple.com/kb/TS1277?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US

I understand the gist of what's going on here, I'm just not sure how permissions need to be set up on the second HDD to accommodate iTunes.

Thanks~~

Comment: Need more information to correctly diagnose what's going on. For example, do you get an error when you try to authorize? Also, how many computers/users have you authorized with that specific Apple ID?

Comment: I've updated my original question with a bit more detail. Thanks~~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the deal w/ iTunes in regards to moving your Users directory to a separate drive or partition; it turns out that the Shared directory *must* remain on the system drive. For example, in my context the path should be `/Mac/Users/Shared` where 'Mac' is my system drive. The other users stay in `/Volumes/Pig/Users/...`, i.e., arrow and wildcat.

I believe the permissions I listed above are incorrect and they've since been changed to:

/Volumes/Pig - 644 system:admin

/Volumes/Pig/Users - 644 system:admin

/Mac/Users/Shared - 777 arrow:admin

Correcting the permissions to their current settings didn't solve the problem on it's own, moving Shared to the same drive as the iTunes binary did.